# Integration in terms of x

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

Evaluating the integral 
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2} +9}}dx$$
so I use tan substitution
$$ x=3\tan t ~\mbox{and}~ dx = 3\sec^{2} t ~dt  $$
after substituting everything in and smplifying im left with 
$$\int \sec t ~dt$$ but I need to have this answer in terms of x, I know 
$$ \sec t = \sqrt{1 + \tan^{2}t}$$ and $$\tan t = \frac{x}{3} $$ so do I just plug in $$\sqrt{1 + (\frac{x}{3})^{2}}$$ just not sure of the final steps I need to get the integral.

Comment: $\int \sec tdt=\ln|\sec t+\tan t|+C$

Comment: If you just sub back in for $x$ without integrating, you should get your original integral back.

Comment: See http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ11/integ11.html

Comment: you can integrate sec in different ways, it is often considered a standard integral - where you suggest the tan = x/3 substitution , you seem to be heading away from the answer - learn one of the integral sec derivations, and take it from there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you reach the integral$$\int \sec t ~dt$$ you have to integrate 
$$\int \sec t ~dt = \ln |\sec t + \tan t| + C$$
Now, since $\tan t = \frac{x}{3}$, then $\cos t = \frac{3}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}$ and so $\sec t = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+9}}{3}$. Then
$$\int \sec t ~dt = \ln |\sec t + \tan t| + C = \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2+9}}{3} + \frac{x}{3} \right| + C$$

Comment: thanks so much !

Comment: After this you could "absorb" $-\ln 3$ into the constant of integration, and also observe the argument of $\ln$ is always positive anyway (even if $x$ is negative), to get a slightly prettier result $\ln (\sqrt{x^2+9} + x) + C$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int \sec t \ dt = \int\sec t\cdot\frac{\sec t + \tan t}{\sec t + \tan t}\ dt$$

And then substitute $u = \sec t + \tan t$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$$\int \frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}=\operatorname{arg\,sh}t=\ln(t+\sqrt{t^2+1}).$$

Comment: What is $arg sh t $ its new to me .

Comment: The inverse of  $\sinh$ (a.k.a. $\operatorname{sh}$). Do you know the hyperbolic functions?

Comment: Yes somewhat...

Comment: Also one more query is it arg or arc as for normal sin we have arc

Comment: Well, the derivatives of the inverse hyperbolic functions (which are logarithms anyway)  are standard.

Comment: It is `arg` (which stands for ‘ argument’).

Comment: Okay thank you for the information and (+1).

Comment: @Bernard Though normally I prefer notation that makes the relationships between different objects explicit -- so $\operatorname{arcsinh}t$ instead of $\operatorname{arg\,sh}t$ -- there's no way I'm going to pass up on a way of legimately including "arg... shit!" in my math.  So thanks for showing me a notation I hadn't seen before. :3

Comment: I know there's also the notation *asinh*, but as far as I know `arcsinh` does not exist, since in $\sinh x$, $x$ is not supposed to be the measure of an arc.

Comment: @Bernard It's what I always use (due to the previously mentioned desire to make relationships explicit being more important than etymological consistency to me) and no one has ever asked me what it is supposed to mean.  Granted, I would prefer to use $\sin^{-1}$ and $\sinh^{-1}$ but unfortunately those can be ambiguous.

Comment: Personally, I never use the hand-held computer form of the functions. So you don't find *arg sh* clear enough?

Comment: @Bernard I don't know that I've ever seen $\sinh$ written $\operatorname{sh}$.  Now that you've pointed that out, sure.  It's clear.  Without that I don't know that I would have known what it meant, though.  I might have thought it was supposed to be something similar to (but different from) the Jacobi elliptic functions.  Which I suppose it is, now that I think about it. :)